# Grab resource URL from a web page

Tags: html

I am sometimes frustated when I want to go to a page from my bookmarks and the page has disappear. 
I also want to build a tool which download the entire webpage when I bookmark it.

For that, I have to grab all urls of ressources linked to the page: javascript, css, images,...

Here all the xpath selectors I thinked:

```
//img[@src]
//link[@href] 
//script[@src]
//object[@data]
//iframe[@src]
//video[@src]
//audio[@src]
```

and also the background images contained in css files.

Could you tell me if I forgot something?

Comment: What are you going to wright? Browser extension? User script? HTML alone wouldn't be sufficient to complete this task.

Comment: Yes, a browser extension for al the bookmark management. And node for the scraping tool. But it's not the purpose of my question.

Comment: Ok, but you still can't rely solely on HTML when it comes to linking external files: this may be done from a script, `@import` or `url()` from a stylesheet, etc.

Comment: My question was not how but what to grab

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to warn you.

Comment: warn that I will not be able to scrap data in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget do that very well

wget --no-parent --timestamping --convert-links --page-requisites --no-directories --no-host-directories -erobots=off http://domain.tld/webpage.html

https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget